# String command in netbeans does not color blue as commmand

Tags: java, netbeans, string

I have a windows vista home premium on my toshibe Lap,
and i use netbeans.

The problem is when i type in netbeans the command "String"
it does not color it bluei (that means that this is a command), but the other commands it does color blue, like "char" , "integer" and so on and so on.

Of course I type the command after the main statement,
and with an uppercase "S",
and still it doesn't color it,

i thought it was a configuration problem,
and i had netbeans 7 something so i deleted the folders:

```
"%appdata%/roaming/netbeans"
```

and some Local config i think like:

```
"%appdata%/Local/netbeans"
```

and tried to install the new version 8.0.2
it all installed ok,
but when I entered the program and typed "String" it still showed in black,
like it's simple text and not a command.

Answer (score 0):

`int` and `char` are [primitive data types](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_datatypes.htm) (and not commands as you are stating). `String` is an object class name.

Netbeans does not highlight object class names during the declaration of the object. This is why the behavior is different.

These threads may be useful:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/26054254/1540660
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/13368546/1540660

Comment: Thank you, smc. now i understand better
about these java variables.
also thanks for the links i entered them
but didn't quite find what i was looking for
so i tried to use "fonts and colors" in NetBeans.
and i colored all the "identifier" in java to blue
becuase i didn't find an option to color
only the "String" object, if you can tell
me a better way to do that please tell.

Thanks,
Yaniv R.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way of changing the color of just this particular element in NetBeans.